# Github cargo build fails for checksum

Tags: github, build, github-actions, rust-cargo, rust-tokio

I have updated project dependencies and vendor them out and tested my changes locally and in docker and it works normally.

When I pushed my change, the GitHub action failed to perform the tests and gave this error

```bash
error: the listed checksum of `<project>/vendor/crates/libc-0.2.137/src/unix/linux_like/linux/gnu/b64/aarch64/int128.rs` has changed:
Error: expected: 1735f6f5c56770d20dd426442f09724d9b2052b46a7cd82f23f3288a4a7276de
actual:   2a242b8a3756afdbf2442da23c014f315c3b7b3d94e50284057420de86c328b8

directory sources are not intended to be edited, if modifications are required then it is recommended that `[patch]` is used with a forked copy of the source
```

I didn't change anything manually or that it can influence the checksum to change and I don't know why this happens. Any ideas?

Comment: can also confirm that pinning that lib to a version did not work. Not it fails with the same error but for another lib